# Multi values for SSRS parameter with Like statement

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2012

IN SSRS, I have a parameter named `Comment` which I set to `Allow multiple values`

[image]

and specified available values for it.

[image]

My problem is that if I select one value, I will get results but if I select more than one, I will get an error.

[image]

The problem is probably because I wrote my SQL statement like this:

```
dbo.tbl_Status.Comments LIKE ('%' + @Comment + '%')
```

NB:  I need to use `LIKE` and not `IN`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to change your query in an expression and concatenate the condition using the `JOIN` expression on your parameter values.

For instance, if you create a report based on the Adventureworks 2014 database you could add a parameter like this:

[image]

With some values that appear in the table:

[image]

If you then enter an expression for your dataset instead of a query like this:

```
="SELECT "
&     "[NationalIDNumber],"
&      "[JobTitle]"
&"FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[HumanResources].[Employee]"
&"WHERE [JobTitle] LIKE '%" & Join(Parameters!jobtitle.Label, "%' OR [JobTitle] LIKE '%") & "%'"
```

It would result in what you want when selecting a single value:

[image]

Because the concatenated expression is this:

```
SELECT [NationalIDNumber]
    ,[JobTitle]
FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[HumanResources].[Employee]
WHERE [JobTitle] LIKE '%Engineer%'
```

And it would also work when you select multiple values:

[image]

Because the expression would result in this:

```
SELECT [NationalIDNumber]
    ,[JobTitle]
FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[HumanResources].[Employee]
WHERE [JobTitle] LIKE '%Engineer%'
    OR [JobTitle] LIKE '%Marketing%'
```

Full .RDL file can be found on [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/208634df53969cf6f47de8cbf92fa404) and requires a local Adventureworks 2014 database.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the solution you mentionned. I tried to reproduce the steps from my end but it's not working... When I select values in the parameter it returned no results even if in the column I have data that match the values... Here is my query :

[image]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/194515)